# Add product custom attribute to order export?

Tags: magento2, product, export

Anyone has any clue on how to add custom product attribute to order export?

Cant realy show any code, cause I have only been googling so far, as I have no clue on how to handle something like this.

Much appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

Modify or override `Mage230/vendor/magento/module-ui/Model/Export/MetadataProvider` File of Core Magento

like This...

enter code herenamespace Magento\Ui\Model\Export;

```
use Emipro\AdminSalesOrderGrid\Ui\Component\Listing\Column\Attribute;
use Magento\Framework\Api\Search\DocumentInterface;
use Magento\Framework\Locale\ResolverInterface;
use Magento\Framework\Stdlib\DateTime\TimezoneInterface;
use Magento\Framework\View\Element\UiComponentInterface;
use Magento\Sales\Api\Data\OrderInterface;
use Magento\Ui\Component\Filters;
use Magento\Ui\Component\Filters\Type\Select;
use Magento\Ui\Component\Listing\Columns;
use Magento\Ui\Component\MassAction\Filter;
```

/**
 * @SuppressWarnings(PHPMD.CouplingBetweenObjects)
 */
class MetadataProvider {
    /**
     * @var Filter
     */
    protected $filter;

```
/**
 * @var array
 */
protected $columns;

/**
 * @var TimezoneInterface
 */
protected $localeDate;

/**
 * @var string
 */
protected $locale;

/**
 * @var string
 */
protected $dateFormat;

/**
 * @var array
 */
protected $data;

/**
 * @param Filter $filter
 * @param TimezoneInterface $localeDate
 * @param ResolverInterface $localeResolver
 * @param string $dateFormat
 * @param array $data
 */
public function __construct(
    Filter $filter,
    TimezoneInterface $localeDate,
    ResolverInterface $localeResolver,
    OrderInterface $order,
    Attribute $attribute,
    $dateFormat = 'M j, Y h:i:s A',
    array $data = []
) {
    $this->attribute = $attribute;
    $this->filter = $filter;
    $this->order = $order;
    $this->localeDate = $localeDate;
    $this->locale = $localeResolver->getLocale();
    $this->dateFormat = $dateFormat;
    $this->data = $data;
}

/**
 * Returns Columns component
 *
 * @param UiComponentInterface $component
 * @return UiComponentInterface
 * @throws \Exception
 */
protected function getColumnsComponent(UiComponentInterface $component) {
    foreach ($component->getChildComponents() as $childComponent) {
        if ($childComponent instanceof Columns) {
            return $childComponent;
        }
    }
    throw new \Exception('No columns found');
}

/**
 * Returns columns list
 *
 * @param UiComponentInterface $component
 * @return UiComponentInterface[]
 */
protected function getColumns(UiComponentInterface $component) {
    if (!isset($this->columns[$component->getName()])) {
        $columns = $this->getColumnsComponent($component);
        foreach ($columns->getChildComponents() as $column) {
            if ($column->getData('config/label') && $column->getData('config/dataType') !== 'actions') {
                $this->columns[$component->getName()][$column->getName()] = $column;
            }
        }
    }
    return $this->columns[$component->getName()];
}

/**
 * Retrieve Headers row array for Export
 *
 * @param UiComponentInterface $component
 * @return string[]
 */
public function getHeaders(UiComponentInterface $component) {
    $row = [];
    foreach ($this->getColumns($component) as $column) {
        $row[] = $column->getData('config/label');
    }

    array_walk($row, function (&$header) {
        if (mb_strpos($header, 'ID') === 0) {
            $header = '"' . $header . '"';
        }
    });

    return $row;
}

/**
 * Returns DB fields list
 *
 * @param UiComponentInterface $component
 * @return array
 */
public function getFields(UiComponentInterface $component) {
    $row = [];
    foreach ($this->getColumns($component) as $column) {
        $row[] = $column->getName();
        $row[] = $column->getTitle();
    }
    return $row;
}

/**
 * Returns row data
 *
 * @param DocumentInterface $document
 * @param array $fields
 * @param array $options
 * @return array
 */
public function getRowData(DocumentInterface $document, $fields, $options) {
    $row = [];
    foreach ($fields as $column) {
        if (isset($options[$column])) {
            $key = $document->getCustomAttribute($column)->getValue();
            if (isset($options[$column][$key])) {
                $row[0] = $this->attribute->getOrderDetails($row[2]);
                $row[] = $options[$column][$key];
            } else {
                $row[] = '';
            }
        } else {
            $row[] = $document->getCustomAttribute($column)->getValue();
        }
    }
    return $row;
}

/**
 * Returns complex option
 *
 * @param array $list
 * @param string $label
 * @param array $output
 * @return void
 */
protected function getComplexLabel($list, $label, &$output) {
    foreach ($list as $item) {
        if (!is_array($item['value'])) {
            $output[$item['value']] = $label . $item['label'];
        } else {
            $this->getComplexLabel($item['value'], $label . $item['label'], $output);
        }
    }
}

/**
 * Returns array of Select options
 *
 * @param Select $filter
 * @return array
 */
protected function getFilterOptions(Select $filter) {
    $options = [];
    foreach ($filter->getData('config/options') as $option) {
        if (!is_array($option['value'])) {
            $options[$option['value']] = $option['label'];
        } else {
            $this->getComplexLabel(
                $option['value'],
                $option['label'],
                $options
            );
        }
    }
    return $options;
}

/**
 * Returns Filters with options
 *
 * @return array
 */
public function getOptions() {
    $options = [];
    $component = $this->filter->getComponent();
    $childComponents = $component->getChildComponents();
    $listingTop = $childComponents['listing_top'];
    foreach ($listingTop->getChildComponents() as $child) {
        if ($child instanceof Filters) {
            foreach ($child->getChildComponents() as $filter) {
                if ($filter instanceof Select) {
                    $options[$filter->getName()] = $this->getFilterOptions($filter);
                }
            }
        }
    }
    return $options;
}

/**
 * Convert document date(UTC) fields to default scope specified
 *
 * @param \Magento\Framework\Api\Search\DocumentInterface $document
 * @param string $componentName
 * @return void
 */
public function convertDate($document, $componentName) {
    if (!isset($this->data[$componentName])) {
        return;
    }
    foreach ($this->data[$componentName] as $field) {
        $fieldValue = $document->getData($field);
        if (!$fieldValue) {
            continue;
        }
        $convertedDate = $this->localeDate->date(
            new \DateTime($fieldValue, new \DateTimeZone('UTC')),
            $this->locale,
            true
        );
        $document->setData($field, $convertedDate->format($this->dateFormat));
    }
}
```

}